# How do I get cordova/phonegap.js to compile a jquery mobile index.html into a native smartphone app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am a little confused and just want to make sure I am doing everything right. I've developed an index.html that uses jquery mobile to load things via AJAX. So when I click links or submit forms, jquery catches the events and handles them via AJAX. However when I uploaded that to phonegap site, waited for a couple of seconds for it to convert that to app(s), and loaded the android app into virtual android emulator, it mostly works fine however some things are still broken. E.g. all form submits re-load the page instead of doing AJAX (common links work fine though). Also I didn't manage to get stuff like navigator.notification.alert() work.

After reading manuals I've noticed that phonegap refers to some phonegap/cordova.js lib that they include in their index.html examples however there is no link to the download. What is this lib? Is this something irrelevant or is it actually the interface that smoothens out the differences between jquery mobile (fixing things like not working AJAX) and also providing additional functionality such as navigator.notification.alert()? If yes, also how do I download it? I think I need to download some SDK, install it and then get the js lib but this sounds suspicious. I mean why do I need to install all that just to get a JS file that I would include in index.html? And finally if all the above is true, when I get that JS lib, will it be a single lib for all devices and phonegap itself will morph it when building for iphone, android, etc or will SDK give me a bunch of lib-s and I'll need to differenciate between them myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this. In case someone stumbles on this thread:

- JS lib gets included like this

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  ```

  and phonegap's online build tool will dynamically insert the proper file in its place and build with it.
- AJAX forms not submitting is a jQuery Mobile bug
  https://github.com/adrianpike/jquery-mobile/commit/88754ac1643a133686b72520d24e32524a737452

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out applaud. They have a great phonegap and JQM(jQuery Mobile) template/demo. Its also a really useful tool to get started developing with phonegap/jqm. I learned alot from it.
http://applaudcloud.com